# What is wrong with my code? My purpose is to create a table which enters rows into a html table

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, html-table, row

What is wrong with my code? My purpose is to create a table which enters rows into a html table with a variable amount of rows. My code returns Warning:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

```
<?php
{
$user=$_SESSION['username'];
$pass=$_SESSION['password'];
}
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","****","*****");
var_dump($con);

if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("****", $con);
$result = mysql_query("select * from `order` WHERE username='$user'");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$html_table = '<table border="1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2""><th>Company     Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    </th><th>Actual Stockprice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Old Stockprice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Cost&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Profit/loss&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><tr>';
foreach($result as $row) {
  $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row['company']. '</td><td>' .$row['amount'].         '</td><td>' .$row['stock']. '</td></tr>';
}


$html_table .= '</tr></table>'; 


$html_table = str_replace('<tr></tr>', '', $html_table);

echo $html_table;        


 } 

?>
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: you're missing a " after border="1 where $html_table is declared first

Comment: per the topic, the issue isn't with the output (yet).  it is with his error message, "My code returns Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()".  result is not an array, it is a PHP Resource. You don't need the  foreach, since you are already have a reference to $row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a solution also:

```
echo '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">';
echo '<th>Company Symbol</th><th>Amount</th><th>Actual Stockprice</th><th>Old Stockprice</th><th>Cost</th><th>Profit loss</th><tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($row as $value) {
        echo "<td>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table'>;
```

Also, I would look into using PDO or mysqli_ because mysql_ is depreciated and insecure.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach loop is broken, it should be

```
foreach($row as $a_variable_name_that_is_not_result) {
  //stuff
}
```

Also, if you're planning on output of a variably number of *columns* you will want to move the `<tr>` tag outside of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: i believe the issue is that the foreach is completely unnecessary

Comment: I think he means to say "a variable number of columns", which would be why there is a `foreach()`. Regardless, this is the source of his error and the point of this question.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$html_table = '<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2"><th>Company     Symbol&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Amount&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    </th><th>Actual Stockprice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Old Stockprice&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Cost&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><th>Profit/loss&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th><tr>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $html_table .= '<tr><td>' .$row['company']. '</td><td>' .$row['amount'].         '</td><td>' .$row['stock']. '</td></tr>';
}

$html_table .= '</tr></table>';
```

Answer (score -1):

First, $reuslt is a PHP resource, as returned from

```
mysql_query("select * from `order` WHERE username='$user'");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

You already have a reference to $row here

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

So just get rid of the foreach loop.  I don't see its purpose at all.

aside from that, there will definitely have to be some changes made to how your final markup is being generated, since it will be "broken"/non valid